# How to get only `.failure` inside of an `else` clause of a `guard case` statement?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out how to make Swift infer that the only possible value in the `else` clause of a `guard case` in the code snipped below is `.failure`. Is it possible or maybe there is some other approach that can be taken?

```swift
enum MyError {
    case error
}

func create() {
    let result = createResult(...) // -> Result<Data, MyError>
        
    guard case let .success(resultData) = result else {
        // maybe somehow get the else case of guard stored in a variable in here, but how???
        switch result {
        case .failure(.error):
            self.isError = true
            return
        }
        // getting "Switch must be exhaustive" error even though .success is not possible and there is only one .error case in the error enum 
    }

    // success code here...
}
```

I tried using regular `switch` from @HangarRash's
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75646125/8954711) and it worked but i would like to avoid nesting for the success part of the function.

Comment: "i would like to avoid nesting for the success part of the function." Do you have multiple `Result`s like this? Otherwise that's not really a lot of nesting, is it?

Comment: Even if the amount of nesting is bearable i would still want to know if it's possible to do this without nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if the amount of nesting is bearable i would still want to know if it's possible to do this without nesting.

Well, most things are possible if you make an extension :)

```
extension Result {
    func tryGetValue(onFailure block: (Failure) -> Void) -> Success? {
        switch self {
        case .success(let x):
            return x
        case .failure(let e):
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
func create() {
    let result = createResult(...)
        
    guard let resultData = result.tryGetValue(onFailure: { error in
        // you can use the closure parameter "error" here...
        // check if it is MyError.error or whatever
        self.isError = true
    }) else { return } // you must return here

    // process resultData...
}
```

This looks quite ugly though to be honest, but indeed, it does not nest the success branch.

What I recommend is converting this to use the regular `try...catch` error-handling, by calling `get` on the `Result`.

```
func create() {
    do {
        let result = try createResult(...).get()
        // process success result...
    } catch MyError.error {
// or catch every error of type MyError
//  } catch let error as MyError {
        self.isError = true
    } catch {} // unreachable
}
```

(If you can change the `createResult` function, you should just change it to `throws`.)

This is easily extendable to multiple `Result`s if you handle the errors all in the same way:

```
func create() {
    do {
        let result1 = try createResult1(...).get()
        let result2 = try createResult2(...).get()
        let result3 = try createResult3(...).get()
        // process success result...
    } catch {
        self.isError = true
    }
}
```

However, the drawback of this is that if more than one of the `Result`s have the same failure type, then you wouldn't know where the error came from in the `catch` block, which means that you cannot handle those results differently.

Comment: `try ... catch` loses type for the error which is the reason i'm using `Result` in the first place. `tryGetValue` does what i want though. Thanks! Just need to call the `block` function with the `e` in failure case.

Comment: @ansavchenco you can do arbitrary pattern matching after the word `catch`, you know. Like `catch let error as SomeErrorType`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point to the `guard` since you need to handle both possible cases. Just fill out the `switch` with the two cases and handle the success code right in the `.success` case.

```
func create() {
    let result = createResult(...) // -> Result<Data, MyError>
        
    switch result {
        case .success(let resultData):
            // success code here...
        case .failure(let error): // Handle any error code
            self.isError = true
    }
}
```

Much simpler and more organized. If the "success" code is long and complicated then put it in a separate function. Something like this:

```
func create() {
    let result = createResult(...) // -> Result<Data, MyError>
        
    switch result {
        case .success(let resultData):
            process(data: resultData)
        case .failure(let error): // Handle any error code
            self.isError = true
    }
}

private func process(data: Data) {
    // complicated data processing
}
```

---

If you want to keep the `guard`, you can replace the `switch` with an `if case let` since you only need to handle the `.failure` case at that point:

```
func create() {
    let result = createResult(...) // -> Result<Data, MyError>
        
    guard case let .success(resultData) = result else {
        if case let .failure(error) = result {
            // print(error) // this will always be .error in your setup
            self.isError = true
        }
        return
    }

    // success code here using resultData
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I would like to avoid nesting as the success part is quite long and has a lot of nesting already. Should have probably mentioned this in the question. I will update the question.

Comment: Refactor all of that success code into a separate function that you call from the `.success` case. Keep your code organized. See updated answer.

Comment: That's not exactly what i want to achieve but thanks for the answer though

Comment: @ansavchenco I added another update to the end of my answer that may more directly answer your question.